# What is the most appropriate HTTP response from a backend service when attempting to remove an entry that no longer exists in the Database?

Tags: http, backend

My team is developing a simple backend service that provides the operations `ADD`, `GET` and `REMOVE` a very simple item. All are triggered by an http request and they do not much besides adding, getting and removing the item from a database.

Regarding the specific scenario in which a `REMOVE` operation is triggered on a item that is not present in the DB (e.g. was removed before), **our question is what should be the response of the service?** We having been debating options like `200 + some specific message`, `410 - resource gone`, amongst other 2XX and 4XX possibilities, but we haven't reached a consensus.

I hope this is not [Bikeshedding](https://exceptionnotfound.net/bikeshedding-the-daily-software-anti-pattern/).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A database record is a resource. If a resource is not found you should return a status of 404.

Comment: 200 OK POST specific message should be used. The Remove request succeeds regardless of the data availability in connection point of view. To inform the user of the data unavailable, specific message in the response can be used.

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the response of the service?

It's important to highlight that [status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) are meant to indicate the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client request. Having said that, [`2xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) status codes are *unsuitable* for this situation and should be avoided:

> The `2xx` (Successful) class of status code indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.

The most suitable status code would be in the [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) range:

> The `4xx` (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

The [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) status code seems to be what you are looking for, as it indicates that the server can't find the requested resource:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.  A `404` status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent; [...]

If you are concerned on how the client will understand the `404` reponse, you could provide them with a payload stating that such resource is no longer available.

---

And just bear in mind that `ADD` and `REMOVE` are not standard HTTP methods. Hopefully that was a typo and you are using [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) (or [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)) and [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) to express operations over your resources.

Comment: I agree with the statement "... are meant to indicate the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client request" but I am not sure I agree with the follow up "Having said that, 2xx status codes are unsuitable..."

Comment: moreover, the fact is that the request is well received, understood, and accepted. But since it was removed before, there is not consequence to the request

Comment: I guess it is a matter of interpretation

Comment: I would add that, according to the RFC, the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the origin server knows, ..., that the condition is likely to be permanent.

Comment: My main concern with the range of 4XX triggers an alert on our monitoring tool, and I am not sure I want that..